# Is generalizing a model, then removing the generalization good for FFNNs?

Tags: machine-learning, dropout, generalization

If one is training a basic FFNN (Feed-Forward Neural Network), one would apply regularizations like dropout, l1, l2 and gaussian noise, so that the model is robust and gives better results for unseen data. But my question is, once the model gives fairly good results, isn't it advisable to remove the reguarizations then train the model again for some time, so that its predictions are more accurate?

Comment: please add the full name of the abbreviation FFNN when first mentioned for clarification.

Comment: If we train the generalised model again, there are chances that it might overfit again.

Answer (score 0):

L1 and L2 regularizations matter only during training, they are a way to update the Network's weights in (hopefully) the right way. Once you use your model for prediction that doesn't matter anymore.

Dropout is active only during training. Once it's done, the Network usese *all* the trained nodes to make a prediction.

In other words, no need to remove regularization techniques manually.

Comment: I don't think you have fully understood the question, my question is: Is it okay to retrain the model for a while **after removing the regularization**?

Comment: Absolutely not, that would push the model back to overfitting